# php constructors

Tags: php, constructor

```
public function __construct($input = null) {
    if (empty($input)){
        return false;
    }
```

and then there's some constructor code...

what I would like to do is for the class to not initialize if I pass an empty variable

$classinstance = new myClass();
I want $classinstance to be empty (or false)

I think this is not possible like this, What's an easy way to accomplish a similar result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make private the normal constructor (so it can't be used from outside the object, like you would if you were making a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)) and create a [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

```
class MyClass {
    private function __construct($input) {
        // do normal stuff here
    }
    public static function factory($input = null) {
        if (empty($input)){
            return null;
        } else {
            return new MyClass($input);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would instantiate a class like this:

```
$myClass = MyClass::factory($theInput);
```

(EDIT: now assuming you're only trying to support PHP5)

Comment: would I still need the __construct ?

Comment: I think you have this the wrong way around. The constructor should be called __construct(), unless you need to support PHP4. __construct is newer.

Comment: (I think that's what he meant)
anyway, I realized why you had the constructor private, but I find I can do all that stuff in the factory. That way I can use the constructor if I need.

Comment: I edited my answer - you guys are right, my note about __construct() was mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a factory method to create the object:

```
private function __construct($input = null) {
}

public static function create($input = null) {
    if (empty($input)) {
        return false;
    }
    return new MyObject($input);
}
```

Comment: and I believe that your create method should be a static method, like in my solution.

Comment: IIRC, PHP will still recognize the call, but putting static is more explicit and ensures no '$this' pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct. A print_r of your new object will show it returns an object.

You could make it throw an exception, but that's unlikely to be the style you want.

+1 on factory methods already posted. Those factory methods might also be like:

```
public static function newCreate( $a ) { return ( !$a ) ? false : new foo( $a ); }
```

I like factory methods :-)